# How to create a CSS class for use in activeClassName

Tags: gatsby, emotion

I'm trying to set the styles for the active link in a navbar using a CSS class generated with [Emotion](https://emotion.sh).

```
<Link activeClassName={activeLink} to="/contact/">Contact</Link>
```

I've defined my style in the same file.

```
import { css } from '@emotion/core'

const activeLink = css`
  color: red;
`
```

The style isn't applied to the active link and I'm getting a console error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `activeClassName` of type `object` supplied to `GatsbyLink`, expected `string`.
```

How can I use an Emotion style with `activeClassName`?

Comment: There are few hacks in here: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/184

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't use `import { css } from '@emotion/core'`, instead you need to use

```
import { cx, css } from 'emotion'

const activeLink = css`
  color: red;
`
<Link activeClassName={cx(activeLink)} to="/contact/">Contact</Link>
```

I hope it's helpful for you.

Alternatively, you may achieve this with the styled element

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled'

const NavLink = styled(Link)`
  &.active {
    color: red;
  }
`
<NavLink activeClassName='active' to="/contact/">Contact</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `activeClassName` only require a string, but have you tried to use `activeStyle` instead of `activeClassName` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<ClassNames/>` component from @emotion/core like this:

```
import {ClassNames, css} from '@emotion/core'

const activeLink = css`
  color: red;
`

const Component = () => {
  <ClassNames>
    {({css}) => (
      <NavLink activeClassName={css(activeLink)} to="/">Home</NavLink>
    )}
  </ClassNames>
}
```